# Writing query with Join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Consider the following tables.

Table Name:

```
order_id   client_id   order_total   order_date ...etc
=======================================================
1001       1          $400           04/10/2016
1002       1          ....
1003       1          ....
1004       2          ....
1005       2          ....
```

Table Name: order_product

```
order_id      product_id
1001          p1
1003          p1
1002          p4
```

I need to write a query to pull all the order information based on product id for a specific client. My query is not returning as expected.

Expected result would be,

```
product_id  order_id   order_total order_date
p1          1001        $400        04/10/2016
p1          1003        $800        ......
```

My Sample query:

```
select *
  from client_order co
  join order_product op
    on co.order_id = op.order_id
  where co.client_id = 1
```

I'm not a big database person, trying to work out some requirements. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below Query,

```
Select op.product_id,co.order_id,co.order_total,co.order_date 
  From client_order co,order_product op 
 Where co.order_id = op.order_id and co.client_id = 1
```

Comment: This is exactly the query I have [u have columns spelled out, I have *], that's  returning a n Empty result set

Comment: dude if you pull select * ...... returning all fields in both tables how both are same explain me.

Comment: On both ways, * and spelling out the column names returns an empty result

Comment: Yeah this query works. I think I don't need a Join I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108847/discussion-between-prabhat-sinha-and-siva).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple [Inner Join](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.2.2/ref/rrefsqlj35034.html) for that.

```
SELECT
    op.product_id
   ,co.order_id
   ,co.order_total
   ,co.order_date
FROM
    client_order co 
    INNER JOIN order_product op ON co.order_id = op.order_id 
WHERE
    co.client_id = [client_id]
```

Comment: I need to pull all the product_id not a specific one

Comment: @Siva ok, the _based on product id for a specific client_ mislead me a bit. I updated the answer to use an inner join

Comment: Inner Join works fine. Yeah, the issue was I was using Join